# How to draw a straight line before and after a wave using siriwave.js

Tags: javascript

I have an issue using `siriwave.js`.
I would like to have a line then the canvas contains the wave, but my problem is that the beginning (at the left) and the end (at the right) of the wave both move. It results that I can't give a sense of continuity between my line and the canvas.

Here's an image to illustrate my problem:

[image: My wave canvas]

This point is moving a very bit up and down.
Does anyone know how to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the issue, we solved using a better global attenuation function.

https://github.com/CaffeinaLab/SiriWaveJS/issues/8